# Angular2 how to do highchart tootip formatter - Additional value

Tags: angular, highcharts, angular2-highcharts

In Series I have used

```
series: [
        {
          name: 'High usage',
          data: highUsage,
          color: '#009DDB'
        },
        {
          name: 'Normal usage',
          data: normalUsage,
          color: '#83C580'
        }
]
```

In tooltip

```
tooltip: { 
    crosshairs: [true, true], 
    formatter: function() { 

    }
}
```

My JSON format is

```
"data": {
    "low_usage": [
      {
        "percentage": 77.9,
        "machine": 3
      },
      {
        "percentage": 22.8,
        "machine": 1
      }
    ],
```

here everything working fine, but I need to show the number of machines also in tooltip like **Percentage: 100% (3 machines)**
What I have to do in the formatter.

```
{
"data":{
  "normal_usage":[  
     {  
        "machine":1,
        "percentage":4.3
     },
     {  
        "machine":0,
        "percentage":0
     }
  ],
  "high_usage":[  
     {  
        "machine":0,
        "percentage":0
     },
     {  
        "machine":0,
        "percentage":0
     }
  ]
},
"error_path":"no error",
"success":true
}
```

This is my input format I send the data based on high usage and low usage

Comment: post your `highUsage` and `normalUsage` data structure

Comment: @user1608841 please check my updated format.

Comment: you must be passing data in different format in series.data attribute correct? e.g data for `highUsage` in series of highUsage must be like 
`{x:1,y:2,name:'high usage'}` just like mention here (array of obje cts)https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.area.data

Comment: I need to see that object which you pass in series. What you have posted is your api response....please post that object u pass to series..check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/series/data-array-of-objects/

Comment: just to illustrate check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/u6rqnv1v/ with percentage value... you need to include percentage in the series data

Comment: To display `machine` in the tooltip, you need to reference `this.point.machine` in the formatter, specifically you would need `return '<b>Percentage: </b>' + this.percentage + '(' + this.point.machine + 'machines)';`. Extending @user1608841 example, see: http://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/u6rqnv1v/1/

Comment: what you have done so far. can you show in stackblitz

Comment: @ewolden I have tried this.point.machine but I got undefined error

Comment: I guess you are not passing data which is expected to show the things on tooltip..please refer above jsfiddle example done by @ewolden and check how we have passed data to series....@Kanagan

Comment: Thanks for all your suggestions, I passed one more data and show the things on tooltip. Thanks @user1608841

Comment: @Kanagan great..shall I post it as answer ?

Comment: @user1608841 Yes please.

Comment: @Kanagan added answer

Comment: mark it as answer so that anyone else who encounter this issue will get help from this post

Answer (score -1):

You need to add more attributes to the series data like below :

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
     tooltip: {
    crosshairs: [true, true], 
        formatter: function () {
        console.log(this)
            return 'value x ' + this.x +
                'value y ' + this.y + 'value percentage '+this.percentage + '<br/>' + this.point.machine;
        }
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Green', 'Pink']
    },

    series: [{
        data: [{
            name: 'Point 1',
            color: '#00FF00',
            percentage:"90",
            machine: 153,
            y: 1
        }, {
            name: 'Point 2',
            color: '#FF00FF',
             percentage:"80",
             machine: 153,
            y: 5
        }]
    }]
});
```

Check how I have passed `percentage` and `machine` in series data object so that those attributes can be accessible in tooltip formatter function using `this`.

Working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/u6rqnv1v/1/)